# How to use filter on whole string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, selector

I got a pictureeditor and a HTML editor. When I change the value of the subline in the piceditor it should update the alt attribute in the html editor.

I use:

```
function refreshEditorAlt(pic,newalt){
  cnt=getEditorContent();
  var newcnt = cnt.replace($(cnt).filter("img[src$='"+pic+"']").attr('alt'), newalt);
  setEditorContent(newcnt);
}
```

It works until the img tags in the source (cnt variable) of the HTML editor are not enclosed by e.g. div tags.

```
//works
<img alt="pic1" src="http://tools.huber-verlag.de/data/18139/1.jpg" /> 
//does not work
<div><img alt="pic1" src="http://tools.huber-verlag.de/data/18139/1.jpg" /></div>
```

I was shure $(cnt).filter looks in the whole cnt.

So the question is, how to filter for an attribute of a tag which is somwhere in a string but not in the root, when seen as DOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter` *filters* the actual elements, which are wrapped (selected) in jQuery object. To go deep down the DOM tree you need to use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(cnt).find("img[src$='"+pic+"']"). ...
```

Or shorter:

```
$("img[src$='"+pic+"']", cnt). ...
```

Comment: First I also tried find but it did not work. Maybe if you can tell me how to use find to get the alt attribute of the third img in the cnt string, by giving the src attribute.